# Reading data from nearest point and joining it to another point layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, basic-license-level

I have a set of points (villages) and another set of grid points that have a distance value. I need to identify the nearest grid point to the village points and then read the distance value and join it to the village.

Can you please tell me how to do this with basic license, and if not, with Standard license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) with Villages as target features and grid points as join features with "CLOSEST" as the match option.

Comment: Yikes that was way too easy. I overlooked the "closest" option completely. Thank you!